# TO_CHAR equivalent in IBM db2 v9.1

Tags: sql, db2

What I want to do is:

Suppose I have a 4 digit and a 3 digit number (`4251` and `573` respectively)
I want to display them in form of 7 digit number like:( `0004251`, `0000573`) respectively.
the `TO_CHAR` scalar function does the job when using IBM db2 version 9.7 but does not work for IBM db2 9.1.

I need a solution for a query which works well in both cases.Does anyone have any idea how to do so?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Since you say v9.1, I'm assuming you mean DB2 for z/OS (mainframe) here. I tested this to work on at least v9.7 for Linux/Unix/Windows (probably earlier versions will work, too, but I don't have an instance older than that lying around).

Have a look at the [LPAD()](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/dzichelp/v2r2/topic/com.ibm.db2z9.doc.sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_bif_lpad.htm) scalar function:

```
SELECT LPAD(your_field, 7, '0')
FROM your_schema.your_table
```